# Netbeans No carga archivos

Tags: jsf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy trabajando con NetBeans ide 11.1, al ejecutar mi proyecto web con jsf abre el index pero cuando doy run file a cada vista no me carga

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, te recomiendo que brindes más detalles acerca de lo que sucede, adjunta a tu pregunta el **error** que recibes en consola o el código en formato texto de donde piensas o identificaste que se encuentra el error para que facilites a los miembros el poder ayudarte revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información ;)

Comment: hola muchas gracias, mi problema viene con el IDE no con el código, si yo ejecuto cada face desde NetBeans dando click derecho runfile no corre me veo obligado a escribir la url en mi maquina, o a correr todo el proyecto desde el index,migre el proyecto a otro pc con versión 8.2 y funciona correcto, no se por que este ide no corre igual